# Split a pattern string into columns in select query

Tags: mariadb, mysql-5.6

I have a `person` table with below structure.

```
CREATE TABLE person(id integer, details text);
INSERT INTO person(id,details) VALUES(1, "name:Tahir,age:30,sex:male");
```

I want to split details column by comma and show results in difference columns. Like, in this example result would be id, name,age, sex

I believe that is possible with aggregate functions and I tried to produce a query like below

```
SELECT id,
if(person.details like '%name:%',cast(substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'name:',-1),',',1) as unsigned),null) as `name`,
if(person.details like '%age:%',cast(substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'age:',-1),',',1) as unsigned),null) as `age`,
if(person.details like '%sex:%',cast(substring_index(substring_index(person.details,'sex:',-1),',',1) as unsigned),null) as `sex`
FROM person
```

above query fetches data correctly for age but name and sex gets 0. Could you please figure out what I am missing here?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cqyqb7Vhvs7kKYifFywmkV/6

Comment: Why are you placing all these values into a single column in 1st place?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have some limitations on db end, can't add new tables/columns so have to improvise with available column that is LONGTEXT `details`. So, I have no other way but find a workaround.

Comment: Don't put the data together if you need to work with it split apart.  Or do the split in your app code.

Answer (score 1):

Does this cover your expected result?

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ':', -1) name,
>        SUBSTRING_INDEX(age, ':', -1) age,
>        SUBSTRING_INDEX(sex, ':', -1) sex
> FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ',', 1) name,
>              SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ',', 2), ',', -1) age,
>              SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, ',', -1) sex
>       FROM   person) t;
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | age | sex 
> :---- | :-- | :---
> Tahir | 30  | male
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5cb3421353991f3a129cf50645af79a9)*

Comment: thanks for the answer but it works fine with the fixed pattern but will not work with dynamic details. For example, if another key:value pair is attached it will not recognize that. Do you think it can be made dynamic to recognize all key:value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Your column is quite like JSON, so perhaps:

```
select
  json_value(j,'$.name') name,
  json_value(j,'$.age') age,
  json_value(j,'$.sex') sex
  from (select concat('{',
                      regexp_replace(details,
                                     '([a-z]+):([a-z0-9]+)(,?)',
                                     '"\\1":"\\2"\\3'),
                      '}') J from person) p;
```

I've run this on an up to date MariaDB, but MySQL wants nothing to do with it (no regexp_replace).